# Existe alguma maneira de configurar o Laravel 4 para usar namespaces?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, namespace

No `Laravel 5`, percebi que adicionaram agora namespaces na pasta de aplicação. Porém as coisas não eram assim na versão `Laravel 4`.

No `Laravel 5`, por exemplo o `Controllers` ficariam assim:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class MeuController extends Controller {}
```

No `Laravel 4`, seria assim:

```
class MeuController extends BaseController{}
```

Porém o mesmo está dentro de uma estrutura de pastas certinha, que daria para implementar o `namespace`, de acordo com o padrão PSR.

Por exemplo, os controllers ficam dentro de `app/controllers`.

Existe alguma maneira de alterar a estrutura do `Laravel 4` para que o mesmo aceito namespaces, como  abaixo?

```
namespace App\Controller;

class MeuController extends BaseController{}
```

Isso vai ser importante para mim, principalmente para evitar conflito de nome de classes, como é o caso da classe `Log`, que impede que eu crie uma modle chamado `Log`, pois isso entraria em conflito. Tudo seria resolvido com um simples namespace.

Comment: Tive um problema parecido com o Yii, no meu caso (imagino que seja o mesmo) o autoload não é feito pelo composer, e sim internamente por metodos mágicos. Logo, se eu tenho duas classes com assinaturas diferentes, mas o mesmo nome "Destaque" sendo instanciadas o seu codigo vai quebrar. Por isso que todas as classes da framework tem prefixos

Comment: @rzani é uma das coisas que já ouvi falar mal do `Yii`: Ele tem a própria gerencia de carregamento de classes, sendo que ele poderia simplesmente usar o namespace. Eu tenho essa solução para o `Laravel`, olhe a minha resposta abaixo :D

Comment: @Wallace então, esse não é bem um problema, da para se utilizar namespace com vendors sem problema. Vale lembrar que o Yii (primeira versão) é de antes de namespace no PHP, era uma solução válida para época. A mesma solução que deu na resposta, também é valida para o Yii, claro que com algumas adquações.

Comment: @rzani isso é bom. Se tivesse alguma maneira de englobar outros frameworks como exemplo, seria ótimo. Mas nada impede que essa resposta possa ser linkada no futuro :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Composer e sua mágicas

É possível sim, mas já aditando que para fazer isso você deve estar acostumado a trabalhar com o `Composer`.

Vamos aos passos necessários:

1 . Adicionar os namespaces em cada arquivo do `Laravel`. Se você não quer correr riscos com seu projeto, sugiro que utiliza uma cópia para testar primeiro (faça um branch novo no `git`, por exemplo).

Você deverá adicionar os namespaces referente à cada pasta.

Por exemplo:

Os arquivos de `app/models` terá o namespace `App\Models`. E assim você terá que fazer para cada pasta, que use classe, e que você deseja adicionar o uso de namespaces.

2 . Abra o seu arquivo `composer.json`. Provavelmente, ele vai ter um trecho assim:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

O que vamos fazer é o seguinte: Todos as pastas onde você deseja usar `namespace`, você vai remover dessa "listinha" acima.

Nesse caso vou remover `app/controllers` e `app/models`.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
```

Agora, você vai adicionar o seguinte trecho ao seu código

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/traits",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],

    "psr-4": {
           "App\\" : "app/",
     }
},
```

Depois de alterar seu `composer.json`, você agora executará um comando dentro da pasta raiz do seu projeto (o local onde está o `composer.json`).

Execute: `composer dump-autoload` ou `composer dump`.

Após  isso, se quiser fazer um pequeno teste para ver se os arquivos foram adicionados ao `autoload`, basta apenas fazer assim:

```
php artisan tinker --env=local
> $model = new App\Models\MeuModel;
```

Se tudo der certo, a instância do model será exibida na tela.

## Modificando o "Vendor Namespace" do seu Projeto

**Pequena explicação do PSR-4**

Note que na configuração do composer, adicionamos o trecho `App\\`.
Isso é uma exigência do Composer para gerar o autoload pelo PSR-4.
No caso, `App` trata-se do namespace base (o nome base do namespace), que faz parte da exigência do padrão do [Psr-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

De acordo com o PSR-4, isso é chamado de **vendor namespace**. Ou seja, é o primeiro nome do namespace.

*Está confuso? Então vou dar um exemplo:*

```
  namespace VendorNamespace\NomeDoPacote;

  class MinhaClasse {}
```

Sendo assim, não é necessário que o vendor namespace seja exatamente o nome da pasta base que estamos apontando para realizar o autoload. Mas inicialmente, como exemplo, vamos eu fiz assim só pra você entender.

Algumas pessoas não gostam de utilizar `App` como **vendor namespace**, por ser muito comum em algumas aplicações.

Então, se você quiser mudar o nome do **vendor namespace**, não é necessário alterar o nome da pasta `app` - como logicamente alguém poderia pensar, mas apenas é necessário mudar a definição feita em composer.json.

Por exemplo: *Não quero que meu namespace seja `App\Models`, mas quero que seja `Project\Models`. Ou seja, quero trocar o **vendor namespace** `App` para `Project`.*

*Como eu faria isso?*

```
 "psr-4" : {
      "Project\\" : "app/",
  }
```

Depois disso, você terá que rodar `composer dump` novamente e alterar **vendor namespace** de cada arquivo .

Se eu tivesse então uma classe chamada `Remessa` dentro da pastas `app/models` teria que ter essa seguinte declaração.

```
#app/models/Remessa.php

namespace Project\Models;

class Remessa extends \Eloquent {}
```

## E as rotas?

Com a implementação dos namespaces no Laravel 4, quando você tiver que usar a definição de rotas, as coisas vão mudar um pouco.

Antes era:

```
Route::get('/', ['uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex']);
```

Agora é:

```
Route::get('/',[
   'uses' => 'App\Controllers\HomeController@getIndex'
]);
```

Comment: Poderia ter a opção de favoritar respostas haha, ótima explicação amigo @WallaceMaxeters.