# Erro ao declarar uma interface a classe no PHP?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes, interface

Estou com dificuldades em declarar uma `interface` a uma `classe` no `PHP` onde estou encapsulando todo o programa com `namespace`. Eu criei uma `interface` chamada **IArquivo** no diretorio `Cnab\Remessa` e defini as funções para essa interface. Depois eu criei uma classe chamada **Arquivo** no diretório `Cnab\Remessa\Cnab240` onde ao tentar declarar a interface a classe, ocorre um erro de interface não encontrada.

**INTERFACE**

```
namespace Cnab\Remessa;

interface IArquivo {

     public function obter_cabecalho(array $parametros);

     public function obter_detalhes(array $parametros);

     public function grava_texto($nome_do_arquivo);

}
```

**CLASSE**

```
namespace Cnab\Remessa\Cnab240;

class Arquivo implements \Cnab\Remessa\IArquivo {

    public function obter_cabecalho(array $parametros){}

    public function obter_detalhes(array $parametros){}

    public function grava_texto($nome_do_arquivo){}

}
```

Comment: Se esta fazendo PDO? e segue um tutorial http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php e não utilizo pdo.

Comment: Tá usando autoload? Sua pergunta precisa de mais detalhes. Está usando composer? Está usando alguma autoload costumizado? Está incluindos os arquivos? Como está fazendo?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, não estou utilizando o autoload, nem o composer. Nesse caso seria necessário utilizar esses caras?

Comment: @BrunoDuarte Se não quiser, pode usar o "include", mas vai ficar desorganizado o projeto!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters sim verdade, recomendo `include` ou `require` é depende declaração.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para você usar classes ou interfaces da maneira que você está usando, você precisa de um `autoload`. Pois você não está incluíndo as classes ou interfaces através do `include`.

Um exemplo simples de autoload seria:

```
spl_autoload_register(function () {
   include(__DIR__ . "/" . $pClassName . ".php");
});
```

Assim, quando você incluísse, estendesse uma classe ou implementasse uma interface, o php automaticamente executaria o include dos arquivos.

Outra boa maneira seria utilizando o [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) em seus projetos.

Com o composer seria basicamente declarando o seguinte código no seu `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
         "Cnab\\" : "pasta_base_do_namespace/",
    }  
}
```

Em seguida, você deve rodar o comando `composer dump` para gerar o autoload da suas classes.

Nessa resposta, explico como utilizar o Composer no Laravel, mas o exemplo pode ser seguido para entender o seu funcionamento (caso você não use o Laravel).

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123110/4995

Comment: Wallace, utilizando o primeiro código como ficaria? Eu teria que criar um arquivo por exemplo: `autoload.php` na raiz da pasta e depois colocaria esse código dentro e desse arquivo, é isso? E depois como ficaria, pra mim trabalha dessa forma com o autoload?

Comment: Sim, se você chama a sua lógica toda no `index.php`, lá é o lugar onde ele deve ficar.